# Blacklisted module is still loaded?

Tags: kernel, pulseaudio, blacklist, ivtv

I have a problem with the module ivtv_alsa being loaded despite me having blacklisted it. No other module depends on it:

```
# lsmod | grep ivtv
Module                  Size  Used by
ivtv_alsa              13768  1 
ivtv                  165297  2 ivtv_alsa
cx2341x                28331  1 ivtv
i2c_algo_bit           13564  1 ivtv
v4l2_common            21457  5 ivtv,tuner,msp3400,saa7115,cx2341x
videodev              130172  8 ivtv_alsa,ivtv,tuner,msp3400,saa7115,cx2341x,v4l2_common
tveeprom               21249  1 ivtv
snd_pcm               102477  6 ivtv_alsa,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_oxygen_lib,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd                    69533  29 ivtv_alsa,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_virtuoso,snd_oxygen_lib,snd_mpu401_uart,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
```

(I did read the other topics on the matter on this forum, but the answers from those did not help.)

I have tried creating a blacklist-ivtv-alsa.conf in /etc/modprobe.d containing

> blacklist ivtv_alsa

and also tried to change it to

> blacklist ivtv-alsa

The module still gets loaded, and this prevents my pm/sleep.d script from unloading the ivtv module.

I have found that it's pulseaudio that uses the ivtv-alsa module, so if do

> killall pulseaudio && sudo rmmod ivtv_alsa

it gets unloaded. The only remedy so far has been to delete the ivtv_alsa.ko module file.

And yes, I did also try to do

> sudo update-initramfs -u

after the blacklisting.

Is there anything else to do? I'm at a loss, and I don't want to have to delete the module after each kernel update - it's a manual step that does not fit well with an automated update system.

FYI: I use ivtv for my TV capture card, but the ivtv_alsa module is not required - it works perfectly well without it.